# How to configure mod_gzip to exclude all but a few mime types?

Tags: regex, gzip, mime-types, http-compression

I need to configure a `.htaccess` file to enable compression of HTTP responses using `mod_gzip`. I can get the basic compression working.

However, I want to **disable** compression for all MIME types, *except* for the following:

- text/*
- message/*
- application/x-javascript
- application/json
- application/atom+xml
- application/xaml+xml

I know I can use statements such as `mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^regex$` to include or exclude or exclude certain mime types, but I can't seem to get it quite right. How should I configure my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
^(?:(?:(?:text|message)\/\*)|(?:application\/(?:x-javascript|json|(?:atom|xaml)\+xml)))$
```

Comment: Thank you. The regex seems to work just fine. Unfortunately, the answer to my question does not solve my bigger problem of getting the entire site to work :-) Looks like I need to dig a little deeper...